# DataTables in Rails -- how do get rid of "Cannot reinitialise DataTable" error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am using DataTables with my Rails app.

For some reason, DataTables/JQuery seems to think I'm trying to reinitialise DataTable. Whenever I load a page that uses DataTables, it gives this error:

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'DataTables_Table_0'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.
To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy
```

Why is this happening? My pages only load the script once as far as I can see and I know that it generates just one table element per page...

**/application/views/layouts/application.html.haml**:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
  %body
    = yield
```

**/application/views/reports/index.html.haml**:

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Short Name
      %th Controls
  %tbody
    - @reports.each do |report|
      %tr
        %td= link_to report.full_name, report_path(report)
        %td
          = link_to "Edit", edit_report_path(report)
          \|
          = delete_link "Delete", report_path(report)
```

I'm pretty sure I've set up the asset pipeline correctly...

**/assets/javascripts/application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require html5shiv
//= require_tree .
```

And I'm pretty sure I'm calling DataTables correctly...

**/assets/javascripts/tables.js.coffee**:

```
jQuery ->
  $('table').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bJQueryUI: true
```

And I don't think any of my gems will be causing the behaviour:

**Gemfile**:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "rails", "3.2.11"
gem "activesupport"
gem "actionmailer"
gem "mail"
gem "railties"
gem "compass"
gem "pg"
gem "sass"
gem "sass-rails"
gem "haml"
gem "haml-rails"
gem "susy"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "google-analytics-rails"
gem "declarative_authorization"
gem "authlogic"
gem "simple_form"
gem "country-select"
gem "rails3-generators"
gem "hirb"
gem "debugger"
gem "redis"
gem "RedCloth"
gem "friendly_id"
gem "high_voltage"
gem "validatious"
gem "houdini"
gem "rspec-rerun"
gem "html5shiv-rails"
gem "normalize-rails"
gem "simple-navigation"
gem "thin"

group :development do
  gem "taps"
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "launchy"
  gem "spork", "0.9.2"
  gem "respec"
end

group :assets do
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "sass-rails"
  gem "coffee-rails"
  gem "compass-rails"
  gem "compass-susy-plugin"
  gem "fancy-buttons"
  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
  gem "jquery-ui-rails"
  gem "uglifier"
end
```

**UPDATE**: I know this has *something* to do with the asset pipeline, because the same code in production on Heroku (after `rake assets:precompile`) is not causing the problem that it is causing here on development (where the app assembles assets for me on-the-fly.)

Comment: jQuery selector `$('table')` is pretty generic. If more than one table in page could be causing issues. Try more specific selector, like an ID. Be a lot better to see browser source code since that's where error is being thrown

Comment: Yes that work thanks. Though I'm not sure why given there is only one table visible in the browser source.

Comment: I think datatables may need ID to use for wrappers, to help keep instances isolated..not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if the dataTables js fires before the table is initialized with data.  Try moving your

= javascript_include_tag "application"

to the bottom of the page.

======

```
!!!
%html
  %head

  %body
    = yield
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to sort out as below

```
$('selector').dataTable({...});
```

1. In place of selector mostly you should use ID,

2. The actual concern is you shouldn't use duplicate ID or if you are using class as selector you shouldn't use that class for multiple elements (sounds annoying) so better to be use the selector as ID (ID shouldn't be duplicate for elements)